# Run python script from CruiseControl.NET

Tags: python, cruisecontrol.net, nant

Is is posible to run a python script from Cruisecontrol.Net ? Is there a CCNEt task or a nant task that can be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a built in python task, but you should be able to execute it by crafting an exec task.